# A question about family of monotonic functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $A$ be any family of monotonic increasing functions defined on the closed interval $[a,b]$. There exists an $M$ such that for any $x$ in $[a,b]$ and any $f$ in $A$, we have:
$|f(x)| \leq M$

Prove:
There exists a sequence of functions $f_n(x)$ in A and a monotonic increasing function $g(x)$ such that $f_n(x) \to g(x)$ if $n \to \infty$ for any $x$ in $[a,b]$.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: sorry, it's 'prove' not 'proof'.

Comment: Look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem

Comment: George, functions f(x) in A are only monotonic, they need not be continuous.

Comment: Perhaps use the fact that A being bounded implies that any monotonic function in A converges to a point by Monotone convergence theorem. If A is closed and bounded define the function f_{n}(x) = g(x) - 1/n. This sequence is monotonically increasing as n -> infinity and converges to g(x) by Archimedean Property.

Edit: I'll write a more complete proof below.

Comment: Still no question in here (or forget the boundedness hypothesis, choose some $f$ in $A$ and define $f_n=f$ for every $n$ and $g=f$.).

Comment: I love when people ask trivial questions and then don't mark the correct answer when someone takes the time to explain it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure you asked what you wanted to ask, since the answer to your question as stated is trivial.

I will assume $A\neq\emptyset$.

Take $f$ in $A$.

Set 
$$
f_n:=f\qquad\forall n\geq 1.
$$

Then $f_n$ converges pointwise to $f$ which is increasing.

Comment: of course the fn should be different for different n.

Comment: @LiXinghe What if $A=\{f\}$? Sorry but at some point, you need to realize that the question is trivial or not correctly stated.

Answer (score 0):

Let $S$ be the set of real numbers such that $S = \{x \ \in \ \mathbb{R} | a \leq x \leq b\}$. We are told that for any monotonically increasing sequences $\{a_{n}\} \ \in \ S, a_{n} \leq M \ \forall \ a_{n} \ \in \ S$. Thus, $\exists \{a_{n}\} \ \in \ S$ that is a monotonically increasing bounded sequence. By the monotone convergence theorem, $\{a_{n}\}$ converges to a point $x \ \in \ S$. Furthermore, we know that $\exists$ a subsequence $\{a_{n_{k}}\}$ of $\{a_{n}\}$ that converges to $x$ as well.

Fix $g(x) \ \in \ S$ to be a constant term $x$ such that $a \leq x \leq b$. Thus, $g(x)$ is a monotonically increasing sequence that converges to the point $x \ \in \ S$. Define $\{a_{n_{k}}\}(x) = g(x) - \frac{1}{n}$. Then by the Archimedean Property we see that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \{a_{n_{k}}\}(x) = x = g(x)$.

Comment: Remark that a monotonically increasing function $\{a_{n}\}$ has the property that $a_{n + 1} \geq a_{n}$ so $g(x)$ fulfills this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I fully agree with Julien: as it stands, the problem is trivial, so the solution proposed by Julien is correct (literally interpreting what you wrote).

Acknowledging, however, the following wording: *"Given any sequence in A, there exists a subsequence such that ..."*, then the question would be as follows.

For the assumption of monotonicity and the fact that each $f$ is bounded, we are in the presence of a sequence of functions of bounded variation on $[a, b]$ for which occurred

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad \sup \{|f_n(x)|; n \in \Bbb N , x\in[a,b] \} \leq K$

and (you rightly noted that the functions can have at most a countable set of points of discontinuity of first kind)

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad  V_a^b(f_n)\leq K$

so there exists a subsequence of $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ that converges at each point of $[a,b]$ to a function $g \in \mathcal V_{[a,b]}$.

Comment: yes, the family A is arbitrary.(And it's an infinite set we suppose.)